# Showing the equivalence: $\frac{\varphi^{n}(1+\frac{1}{\varphi})-\psi^{n}(1+\frac{1}{\psi})}{\sqrt{5}}=\frac{\varphi^{n+1}-\psi^{n+1}}{\sqrt{5}}$

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

For a school project, I want to explain the proof, that the Moivre/Binet formula for calculating the $n$-th number of the Fibonacci-Sequence works. I got an inductive proof from the [German Wikipedia article of the sequence](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci-Folge#Induktiver_Beweis). The problem is, that I don't understand how to transpose $$\frac{\varphi^{n}(1+\frac{1}{\varphi})-\psi^{n}(1+\frac{1}{\psi})}{\sqrt{5}}$$ to $$\frac{\varphi^{n+1}-\psi^{n+1}}{\sqrt{5}}$$
I already calculated that the $\varphi$ part is numerical equal before and after.

P.S Hopefully someone will help me (I am posting this with explicit authorization from my teacher), please correct the title, it was the best i could think of.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Definition:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)** In mathematics, two quantities are in the golden ratio if their ratio is the same as the ratio of their sum to the larger of the two quantities.

If we express this definition algebraically, two quantities $a>b>0$ are said to be in the golden ratio $\varphi$ if:
$$\frac{a+b}{a}=\frac{a}{b}=\varphi$$
Hence, by using the fact that $\dfrac{b}{a}=\dfrac{1}{(\frac{a}{b})}$, we have:
$$\frac{a+b}{a}=1+\frac{b}{a}=1+\frac{1}{\varphi}$$
Hence, we have the following equivalence:
$$\varphi\equiv 1+\frac{1}{\varphi}\tag{1}$$
If we multiply both sides by $\varphi$ and rearrange, we obtain a quadratic equation:
$$\varphi^2-\varphi-1=0 \tag{2}$$
Since $\psi$ here represents the conjugate of the golden ratio, and the conjugate will be the other root of the quadratic on $(2)$, we similarly have:
$$\psi\equiv 1+\frac{1}{\psi} \tag{3}$$
Hence, if we substitute $(1)$ and $(3)$, we obtain the result you require.